# Command to create launcher (behind the Xfce/Thunar GUI)

Tags: xfce, command, thunar, launcher

Thunar has an option when right-clicking the desktop to create desktop-files/launchers.

[image]

[image]

Is there a command behind this GUI that could be used in other contexts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just creating a [.desktop file](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) in the `~/Desktop` folder.

You can create these files manually with a text editor or using any other program that can write an INI style file.

A .desktop file can be also be installed with the [`xdg-desktop-icon`](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-desktop-icon.html) tool.

**Edit**

To find the process that has created a window under X.

1. Start a terminal
2. Run `xwininfo` and click in the window you are interested in, note the "Window id"
3. Run `xprop -id XXXX | grep PID` where `XXXX` is from `xwininfo`, note the PID
4. Run `ps aux | grep XXXX` where `XXXX` is the PID from `xprop`

On Xfce, the program is:

```
exo-desktop-item-edit --display=:0.0 --create-new --type Application file:///home/$USER/Desktop
```

Comment: I know what are and how  desktop files work. I am strictly referring to the GUI from my second image. Possibly that is a GUI for `xdg-desktop-icon`. I want a command that could start that GUI.

Comment: @cipricus I've edited the answer to explain how to find the command for an X window.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Now I can use that command in the file `/.local/share/applications/Create new desktop launcher.desktop` and create such launchers outside Xfce/Thunar, or I can add it in other file mansagers like Nautilus or PCManFM.

Comment: To create an application launcher in `/.local/share/applications` that can be searched and launched with a tool like Synapse, Dash, Whiskermenu, Krun etc (instead of one one the Desktop), the command is `exo-desktop-item-edit --display=:0.0 --create-new --type Application file:///home/$USER/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement based on the first answer and its comments:

For a *Thunar action in order to create a launcher in the current directory*: open Thunar, select 'Edit - Configure custom actions', add the command:

```
sh -c 'exo-desktop-item-edit --create-new --type Application .'
```

The last dot (`.`) *specifies the current directory* as location for the creation of the file. (Source [link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-i-specify-the-current-directory-on-the-command-line-648525/#post3181394).)

Under "Appearance conditions" check 'Directories'.